# What does "NO MATCH" in my fsck_hfs output mean?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bad-sectors, fsck

I am trying to check external USB 3.5" HDD for bad sectors and fix them if possible.

```
$ sudo fsck_hfs -fy -S /dev/disk2
```

Gives following output:

```
** /dev/rdisk2 (NO WRITE)
Scanning entire disk for bad blocks
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
volumeType is 0
0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00fe       |................|
01c0:  ffff eefe ffff 0100 0000 2f7b a8ae 0000       |................|
01d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
block 8509328:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509329:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509330:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509331:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509332:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509333:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509334:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 8509335:  *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765384:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765385:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765386:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765387:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765388:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765389:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765390:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765391:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765472:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765473:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765474:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765475:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765476:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765477:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765478:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765479:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765480:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765481:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765482:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765483:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765496:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765497:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765498:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765499:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765500:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765501:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765502:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765503:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765528:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765529:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765530:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765531:   *** NO MATCH ***
block 2305765532:   *** NO MATCH ***
```

Is it good or bad? How to understand this output?

**UPDATE:**

Found here: https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/fsck_hfs/

```
EXIT VALUES
 fsck_hfs indicates some status by exit value.  The current list of exit status results is:
       0       No errors found, or successfully repaired.
       3       A quick-check (the -n option) found a dirty filesystem; no repairs were made.
       4       During boot, the root filesystem was found to be dirty; repairs were made, and the
               filesystem was remounted.  The system should be rebooted.
       8       A corrupt filesystem was found during a check, or repairs did not succeed.
       47      A major error was found with -E.
```

Looks like my HDD is fine:

```
volumeType is 0
```

But I wanna understand other output lines

Comment: You cannot (always) surmise the [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of a macOS program based on the visible output of the program. `volumeType` doesn't mean "exit value." See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

Modern drives automatically lock out bad sectors on write.

Back up all the data you care about from that drive and then  format the whole drive with "zero all data" selected.

If you can read the SMART data counters for the drive, look to see if the counters for pending and locked out / remapped  bad sectors are still zero. If they're nonzero, then your drive is probably dying and should not be trusted with important / irreplaceable data.

Comment: Its so difficult to backup all data, copy operations takes days and pretty slow

Answer (score 0):

I was in this same situation with an external device that I was attempting to repair.

Long story short, your device has bad blocks that are not *currently* allocated to a file on the filesystem, but *because* `fsck_hfs` has identified them, it means the drive electronics itself was not able to remap them or "hide" them from the operating system. This is not good. **You cannot rely on this device anymore to safely store new data***, and you should probably copy whatever data is currently on the device somewhere else.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297874/324784) from the Apple Stack Exchange site for more details.

Also note that you cannot (always) surmise the [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of a macOS program—or any Unix program, generally—just based on the output it prints to the terminal.

Your `fsck_hfs` command most likely failed with exit code 8 (mine did), which you can check by typing `echo $?` immediately after the command finishes.

---

* if you're really tight on funds, there *may* be a way to create a new filesystem on the device that avoids the bad areas (such things are possible, for example, with [`mkfs.ext2`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext2), on Linux, which has an argument for specifying a list of bad blocks), but that's kind of beyond the scope of your question, and chances are the device is at the end of its useful lifetime anyway.